# Replace character ý to \n

Tags: sed, replace

I hope someone can help or point me to the right direction.  I am searching very hard for 2 weeks now.

Here is the thing, I am on Linux (RHEL) and I have to replace character `ý`to a `\n` from an input stream.

I tried `awk '{gsub(/ý/,"\n")}1'` and `sed '$ s/ý/\\n/g'` with no success.
Also tried this trick:
`sed '$ s/ý/\\
/g'` with no luck.

I am sure I am looking for the right character because if I open the file with VI this is what I see:
`DESCRIPTION : test line 1ýtest line 2ýtest line 3`

For info, `ý` is an UniVerse multi-value separator.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's going to be something locale-related.  Try searching on this site for `locale` along with `sed` or `awk`.  Solution might be as easy as `LC_ALL=C sed 'your script'`

Comment: Please add the output of this command `od -tx1c testfile` (assuming testfile is the name of the file you open in vi) to the question.

Comment: Given that the "UniVerse multi-value separator" is either 252 (0xFC) or 253 (0xFD) and that what you see is a `ý` (ISO-8859-1 character 0xFD) is seems reasonable to assume that the `ý`'s are actually bytes 0xFD (or 375 in octal). So, does this command work for you: `sed 's/\xfd/\n/g'` ?

Comment: Hi @Isaac, you are right with the octal value of 375, that is that I got from od -tx1c.  I used ``sed 's/\xfd/\n/g'`` and it works!!  The document now prints as it should.  MANY THANKS TO YOU !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character (as seen in vi) may be the conversion from several possible encodings (utf8, ASCII, ISO8859-1, etc). Therefore, it is ambiguous when you declare:

> ...if I open the file with VI this is what I see: DESCRIPTION : test line 1ýtest line 2ýtest line 3

To remove ambiguity you should provide an hex (or octal) dump of the file contents. The command:

```
od -tx1c testfile
```

will give such UN-ambiguos dump of the file.

Before having a dump of the file I said:

> Given that the "UniVerse multi-value separator" is either 252 (0xFC) or 253 (0xFD) and that what you see is a ý (ISO-8859-1 character 0xFD) is seems reasonable to assume that the ý's are actually bytes 0xFD (or 375 in octal).

You  confirmed [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546381/replace-character-%c3%bd-to-n?noredirect=1#comment1014889_546381) that that is actually the value inside the  file.

Knowing that, the command:

```
sed 's/\xfd/\n/g' testfile
```

Should work, which you also confirmed to be the solution.